# I am adding stripe subscription to bubble app but facing this problem "Stripe error: The search feature is temporarily unavailable in your region."

Tags: stripe-payments, bubble.io

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZhpB.png)

Can somebody tell me what is the issue and how to resolve this?

I tried changing Business location and Type of business both individual and sole proprietor, but still showing same error message.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is your region? Is it perhaps subject to US sanctions?

Answer (score 1):

Stripe's documentation mentions that Search is currently not available for India merchants : https://docs.stripe.com/search#regional-availability. If your Stripe account is not based in India and are seeing that error message, then you should probably reach out to Stripe Support to find out why you're seeing that error message